# Is there any ongoing research in nuclear pulse propulsion?

Tags: launch, propulsion, nuclear-pulse-propulsion, research, nuclear

Nuclear pulse propulsion seemed to be quite actively researched up until the 1990's, with a few projects that saw some rather promising results (some that could theoretically reach over 4% light speed.)

However, it all seems to have gone a bit quiet since then - is there any ongoing research into this area, or have plans been shelved for now? For a very promising technology (on the surface at least) that could hugely cut journey times, it seems a shame if not much is being invested in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=440), titled *Nuclear Pulse Propulsion Re-Examined*, was published in late '05.

There is also [this article](http://www.scifiideas.com/sfi/technology/nuclear-pulse-propulsion/), which was posted in early '12.

Unfortunately, despite much Googling, I wasn't able to find any real *research* on the subject after about the '90s, when [Project Medusa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pulse_propulsion#Medusa) was started by NASA.

Comment: .. so you could answer that question with "no, not as of summer 2013"?

Comment: @mart: I would say there is a minimal amount of work in the last 2 decades, but no real research as of summer 2013.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto - directed energy weapons' work is still classified, and that's where Orion's pulse units come in. Larger engineering work still needs some re-design, though.

Comment: Recent work on nuclear pulse propulsion has tended to be heavily conflated with inertial-confinement fusion and Z-pinch.